# how to upload and download images on kinvey server

Tags: android, kinvey

hey I am using below code in my android app. it is uploading images on kinvey server successfully.but when I try to open it by using download link http://storage.googleapis.com/6e1e6118eb264d42902a4b280cd5aa7b/myFile/abc.jpg given on  kinvey under  Files collections it shows "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
  <Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
     </Error>
```

and when I try to download that file , it shows  blob not found, I  don't know  where is  the  problem, could  you please  point it  out,I  have  given the  download  Log  below....
thanks in advance

this is my image uploading code

```
public void  upload()
{
    try{
        File file = new File(""+Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/aa.jpg");
        FileMetaData metadata = new FileMetaData("myFile");
        //     metadata.setAcl((new KinveyMetaData()).AccessControlList().setGloballyReadable(true)); //create the FileMetaData object
        metadata.setPublic(true);  //set the file to be pubicly accesible
        //  metadata.setAcl((new KinveyMetaData.AccessControlList()).setGloballyReadable(true)); //allow all users to see this file
        metadata.setFileName("abc.jpg");

        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(file);
        UploaderProgressListener upl=new UploaderProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                System.out.println("upload success!");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
                System.out.println("upload progress change!");
            }
            @Override
            public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("upload progress change -> " + uploader.getUploadState());
            }
        };
        mKinveyClient.file().upload(metadata,fin,upl);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't upload! -> " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is my images downloading code

```
public void download() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/aa11.jpg");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        DownloaderProgressListener dpl=new DownloaderProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void progressChanged(MediaHttpDownloader mediaHttpDownloader) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("progress updated: "+mediaHttpDownloader.getDownloadState());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                System.out.println("successfully download file");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                // System.out.println("failed to download file :->"+throwable.getCause());
                System.out.println("failed to download file :->"+throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                System.out.println("failed to download file :->"+throwable.getStackTrace());

            }
        };
        Query myQuery=new Query();
        myQuery.equals("id","myFile");
        client.file().download(myQuery,fos,dpl);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("in catch block,could'nt download file ---->"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Log for downloading image code...., for  downloading  I  got  "blob  not  found" please  check  the  log....

> 16:09:46.036 13008-13008/com.kinvey.sample.statusshare I/System.out:
>   going to download new file in aa1.jpg
>            11-02 16:09:46.051 13008-13341/com.kinvey.sample.statusshare I/System.out: progress updated: DOWNLOAD_IN_PROGRESS
>           11-02 16:09:46.051 13008-13341/com.kinvey.sample.statusshare I/System.out: progress updated: INITIATION_STARTED
>             11-02 16:09:46.870 13008-13341/com.kinvey.sample.statusshare I/System.out: failed to download file :->
>             11-02 16:09:46.870 13008-13341/com.kinvey.sample.statusshare I/System.out: REASON: BlobNotFound
>             11-02 16:09:46.870 13008-13341/com.kinvey.sample.statusshare I/System.out: FIX: This blob not found for this app backend
>              11-02 16:09:46.870 13008-13341/com.kinvey.sample.statusshare I/System.out: EXPLANATION:
>   The file being downloaded does not exist.
>              11-02 16:09:46.890 13008-13341/com.kinvey.sample.statusshare I/System.out: failed to
>   download file :->[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@33e9dd19

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel,

1. What version of the Android SDK are you using?
2. Do you consistently see this issue with other file upload / downloads as well or does it just happen sometimes?
3. Do you see any errors generated during the upload process any time?

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey Support

Comment: I am using Android  SDK 22.  everytime it is showing this issue during downloading the files . uploading  of file is fine. there is no errors generated during the upload process .